# How to select a date range from a JSON string by using jq?

Tags: json, macos, shell, jq

I have a JSON string like this (MacOS):

```
[{
    "id": 3624,
    "created_at": "2016-10-21T20:51:16.000+08:00",
  },
  {
     "id": 3625,
    "created_at": "2016-10-22T08:09:16.000+08:00",
  },
 {
     "id": 3626,
    "created_at": "2016-10-23T09:19:55.000+08:00",
  }]
```

I wanna select "created_at" from "2016-10-21" to "2016-10-22";
I wanna get result like this:

```
[{
    "id": 3624,
    "created_at": "2016-10-21T20:51:16.000+08:00",
  },
  {
     "id": 3625,
    "created_at": "2016-10-22T08:09:16.000+08:00",
  }]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

**The problem is solved.**
Now,i use this code to select date right to the minute,i hope it's useful for others:

```
jq --arg s '2016-10-26T18:16' --arg e '2016-10-27T20:24' '[($s, $e) | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M") | mktime] as $r
  | map(select(
        (.updated_at[:19] | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S") | mktime) as $d
          | $d >= $r[0] and $d <= $r[1]))' <<< "$requestJson"
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON; the trailing commas need to go.

Comment: Even with the expanded scope of including the time of day, a text-based solution is simpler: `jq --arg s '2016-10-21T20:51' --arg e '2016-10-22T08:09' '
  map(select(.created_at | . >= $s and . <= $e + "z"))`. Generally, please don't expand the scope of your question or change the requirements after the fact, because that may invalidate existing answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a more robust solution, it would be better to parse the dates to get its components and compare those components. The closest you can get is to use `strptime/1` to parse the date which returns an array of its components.  Then compare the components to check if it's in range.

The array that `strptime` returns are the components:

```
year (%Y)
month (%m)
date (%d)
hours (%H)
minutes (%M)
seconds (%S)
day of week (%w)
day of year (%j)
```

Since you're only comparing the dates, the comparisons should only look at the first 3 components.

```
$ jq --arg s '2016-10-21' --arg e '2016-10-22' '
[($s, $e) | strptime("%Y-%m-%d")[0:3]] as $r
  | map(select(
        (.created_at[:19] | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")[0:3]) as $d
          | $d >= $r[0] and $d <= $r[1]
    ))
' input.json
```

Since you're running on a Mac, I'd expect these methods would be available to you in your build.  You may have to make adjustments to the format of the dates for it to work as expected.  As you can see in the comments, we had to massage it a bit to make it work.

Comment: Intriguing - didn't know that `jq` can do all that. Your solution works fine on Linux, but on a Mac (macOS 10.12) you get: `date "2016-10-21T20:51:16+08:00" does not match format "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z"`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a way to verify a fix. Mac is probably interpreting the timezone part differently. I think it might work if that part was stripped out prior to parsing. `... (.created_at[:19] | strptime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")[0:3]) as $d ...`

Comment: On Mac, you also need to strip off the decimal portion of the seconds (or match `.000` literally).

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for verifying.

Comment: Actually, the solution with `%Z` only works _accidentally_ on Linux: `%Z` represents the time-zone *name*, and is completely ignored by `strptime()` - whatever its value. That means it effecitvely _ignores_
the `.000+08:00` part. If you tried to fix that by switching to `%z`, the time-zone *offset* specifier, the fractional part would trip you up on Linux as well.
Since neither platform can properly deal with the fractional part and can therefore not even get to the offset part, using `.created[:19]` to only parse the abstract date + time part is the right solution for _both_ platforms.

Comment: On a related note: `%z` doesn't support _separators_ in the offset string, so only `+0800` would be recognized, not `+08:00`, as in the input. While on Linux the _format_ of `%z` is enforced during parsing, its _value_ is again _ignored_:
the input is effectively treated like a local date, whatever offset is specified. On the Mac, by contrast, a `%z` value is properly applied: the date is converted to a _local_ date on parsing.

Comment: @mklement0: Thanks for the insight, I'll take your word for it.  I guess it would be best if we ignored the decimal and timezone all together. I ran some tests on Linux and changing the timezone did not seem to effect the returned date.

Answer (score 11):

Using command-line JSON parser [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), as requested:

<sup>Note:  [Jeff Mercado's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40211953/45375) demonstrates a lot of great advanced `jq` techniques, but for the specific problem at hand I believe that the *text*-based approach in this answer is much simpler while still being flexible enough.</sup>

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Create variable with sample input.
IFS= read -r -d '' json <<'EOF'
[
  {
    "id": 3624,
    "created_at": "2016-10-21T20:51:16.000+08:00"
  },
  {
     "id": 3625,
    "created_at": "2016-10-22T08:09:16.000+08:00"
  },
  {
     "id": 3626,
    "created_at": "2016-10-23T09:19:55.000+08:00"
  }
]
EOF

# Use `jq` to select the objects in the array whose .created_at
# property value falls between "2016-10-21:T20:51" and "2016-10-22T08:09"
# and return them as an array (effectively a sub-array of the input).
# (To solve the problem as originally stated, simply pass "2016-10-21" 
#  and "2016-10-22" instead.)
jq --arg s '2016-10-21T20:51' --arg e '2016-10-22T08:09' '
  map(select(.created_at | . >= $s and . <= $e + "z"))
' <<<"$json"
```

- Arguments `--arg s '2016-10-21T20:51'` and `--arg e '2016-10-22T08:09'` define variables `$s` (start of date+time range) and `$e` (end of date+time range) respectively, for use inside the `jq` script.
- Function `map()` applies the enclosed expression to all the elements of the input array and outputs the results as an array, too.
- Function `select()` accepts a filtering expression: every input object is evaluated against the enclosed expression, and the input object is only passed out if the expression evaluates to a "truthy" value.
- Expression `.created_at | . >= $s and . <= $e + "z"` accesses each input object's `created_at` property and sends its value to the comparison expression, which performs *lexical* comparison, which - due to the formatting of the date+time strings - amounts to *chronological* comparison.

  - Note the trailing `"z"` appended to the range endpoint, to ensure that it matches all date+time strings in the JSON string that *prefix-match* the endpoint; e.g., endpoint `2016-10-22T08:09` should match `2016-10-22T08:09:01` as well as `2016-10-22T08:59`.
  - This lexical approach allows you to specify as many components from the beginning as desired in order to narrow or widen the date range; e.g. `--arg s '2016-10-01' --arg e '2016-10-31'` would match all entries for the entire month of October 2016.